# ValueError: could not convert string to float: Voltage 1

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

sorry, I'm just beginning and I don't really understand what's going on in this plot:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


File = open('file.txt', 'r')
readFile = File.read()

data = []
split_data = readFile.split('\n')

for line in split_data:
    split_line = line.split('\t')
    if len(split_line) == 4:
            if '[V]' not in line:
                    data.append(line)


voltage, current, abscurrent, time = np.loadtxt(data, delimiter='\t', unpack=True)

plt.plot(voltage, current)
```

The file.txt looks like this:

```
Starttime: 28.11.2016,  12:01:11 

Iterations SMU1: 1 

Configuration: from -2.0V to 2.0V in 0.100V-steps, hold: 0.1s, stop: 0.0s, repeated: 1x


Voltage 1   Current 1   absCurrent 1    Time
[V] [A] [A] [s]

-1.99993e+00    -5.35746e-07    5.35746e-07 4.802936e+02
-1.89992e+00    -4.82880e-07    4.82880e-07 4.805996e+02
-1.79997e+00    -4.34462e-07    4.34462e-07 4.809054e+02
-1.69994e+00    -3.89697e-07    3.89697e-07 4.812115e+02
-1.59992e+00    -3.48121e-07    3.48121e-07 4.815175e+02
-1.50000e+00    -3.10000e-07    3.10000e-07 4.818237e+02
```

Then I always get this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: Voltage 1
```

If I delete this line, the graph is plotted normaly...
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It is likely because this line contains four tabs:

```
Voltage 1   Current 1   absCurrent 1    Time
```

That is what this condtition looks for:

```
    split_line = line.split('\t')
    if len(split_line) == 4:  # Are there four tabs?
```

You could replace the tabs with spaces maybe?

Comment: no, there are just 3. I already tried to add another restriction
    [and 'Voltage':]
in order to  eliminate the line, but the problem remains

Answer (score 0):

It's clearly trying to interpret that string as a float.  That line looks like a header line, but with `unpack` you don't need that.

So you just need to make sure that the `data` list does not include it.  `data` should only include the lines with the 4 floats.  You are already putting a lot of work into filtering out the other header lines.  Complete the job.

Have you, during any tests or debugging, printed `data`?

---

`loadtxt` splits the data lines on the delimiter and then converts each string to the required data type.  The default is float.

```
Out[65]: ['-1.50000e+00', '-3.10000e-07', '3.10000e-07', '4.818237e+02']
In [66]: [float(astr) for astr in line.split()]
Out[66]: [-1.5, -3.1e-07, 3.1e-07, 481.8237]

In [67]: line='Voltage 1 \t  Current 1 \t  absCurrent 1 \t   Time'
In [68]: line.split('\t')
Out[68]: ['Voltage 1 ', '  Current 1 ', '  absCurrent 1 ', '   Time']
In [69]: float(_[0])
...
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Voltage 1 '
```

Comment: `'V' not in line` should skip both the `[V]` line and `Voltage 1` line.  Or if needed skip lines with `Voltage`.